# Por que sites do governo não têm certificados de segurança?

Tags: segurança

Por que muitos sites do governo brasileiro costumam não ter certificados de segurança válidos?

Exemplos:

https://www.ibama.gov.br/

https://www.ibge.gov.br/

https://www.funai.gov.br/

https://www.brasil.gov.br/

https://www.senado.gov.br/

Sobre o fato de não receberem informações, não acho que isso seja verdade. O site do Senado faz enquetes que, embora não reflitam a população brasileira como um todo (eles fazem questão de salientar) devem ter alguma utilidade. Então, eu realmente gostaria de entender porque estes sites não têm isso. Deveriam ter? É problema de custo? De quanto dinheiro estamos falando?

Talvez seja custo, talvez seja incompetência. Ainda assim, é algo que quem entende de criptografia e segurança em redes deve saber. E eu não vejo como criptografia e segurança de redes está "fora de escopo" neste site.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so].  Esta sua pergunta, além de muito ampla pode dar margem a opiniões. Faça um passeio pelo [tour] e depois você pode [edit] sua pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Falta de dinheiro, capacidade de gestão e descomprometimento.

Comment: Talvez porque a maior parte desses sites limita-se apenas a disponibilizar dados, e não receber.

Comment: Talvez não ajude a salvar a sua questão, mas poderia dar uns exemplos desses sites.

Comment: A pergunta não é sobre "segurança e criptografia", é sobre a motivação/competência/funcionamento de diversos setores de TI de diversas instituições governamentais. A não ser que um funcionário de cada um sites citados venha aqui explicar o motivo, não há resposta possível.

Comment: Essa pergunta [está sendo discutida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4620/215)

Comment: Dei -1 pelo que expliquei no meta.

Comment: Bom dia Rodrigo eu não negativei, mas votei sim por fechar e não é pelo motivo que você acha (*E eu não vejo como criptografia e segurança de redes está "fora de escopo" neste site.*), mas sim pelo que eu já comentei no meta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4620/pergunta-negativada-e-fechada-mas-que-parece-ok#comment14897_4620

Comment: @mgibsonbr, você excluiu sua resposta?

Comment: @Rodrigo Sim, pois a situação estava ficando por demais confusa. Se você quiser aprender mais sobre a Infraestrutura de Chave Pública, eu acabei de abrir [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101611/215) que - espero - possa responder às suas principais dúvidas. Eu mesmo devo copiar partes da minha resposta excluída pra lá, se ninguém der uma resposta melhor antes. Mas essa pergunta daqui de fato não tem como responder objetivamente (o que eu havia falado sobre a ICP-Brasil é somente parte do motivo, mas a realidade é que muitos sites do governo simplesmente não o usam, e não sei pq).

Comment: OK. Obrigado, mano.

Comment: O que eu acho estranho é que a maioria não deu a mínima sobre a qualidade dos serviços de informática nas instituições governamentais brasileiras. Estão muito preocupados sobre "o que é uma pergunta válida", mas se lixando sobre "o nosso país tem uma rede de informações segura, ou estamos à mercê de hackers de qualquer nacionalidade?". Infelizmente, depois de ver tantas coisas absurdas, no governo e fora dele, esse descaso realmente não me assusta.

Comment: @Rodrigo, não é o fato que a maioria não dá a miníma, sua pergunta está totalmente fora do escopo do StackOverflow, pois não tem como responder objetivamente a sua pergunta, como já disseram, os motivos podem ser muitos, o maior deles pra mim com certeza é o descaso.