# Quais os impactos na segurança de um site que possui certificado inválido?

Tags: segurança, ssl, certificado-digital

Muitos sites do governo brasileiro costumam não ter certificados de segurança válidos. Exemplos:

https://www.ibama.gov.br/ (validade expirada)
https://www.ibge.gov.br/ (auto-assinado, URL inválida)
https://www.funai.gov.br/ (auto-assinado)
https://www.brasil.gov.br/ (CA desconhecido: ICP-Brasil)
https://www.senado.gov.br/ (CA desconhecido: ICP-Brasil, URL inválida)

Na maioria dos casos o *browser* diz que o "certificado raiz da autoridade de certificação não é confiável", e outros ainda estão simplesmente com a validade expirada. Essa situação é incomum em sites comerciais, mas de vez em quando também topo com um desses. E naturalmente, eu próprio tenho certa dificuldade de manter os sites que gerencio sempre com certificados válidos.

É necessário que um site tenha certificado válido para que a comunicação com ele seja segura? Por que? Alguns desses sites do governo têm funções muito importantes (ex.: Receita Federal, Ministério do Trabalho, Siape...), é seguro continuar utilizando-os apesar do alerta de segurança apresentado? (alguns chegam mesmo a **instruir** o usuário a ignorar esses alertas)

Já me foi sugerido (pelo meu antigo provedor de hospedagem) usar certificados do [cacert.org](http://www.cacert.org/) em vez de um auto-assinado, pois eles "ainda não são reconhecidos pelos principais *browsers*, mas muitos sistemas já aceitam" (ou seja, *ainda é invalido!*). Seria essa uma prática aceitável? Posso simplesmente dizer pros meus usuários ingnorarem o alerta de segurança e pronto, tal como esses sites do governo fazem? Que impactos um certificado inválido tem na segurança de um site?

Comment: Espero que alguma resposta comente do ICP Brasil, que é o problema da maioria dos sites mencionados, e é um problema diferente dos já ditos aqui: O Brasil inventou uma autoridade certificadora que (ainda?) não é acreditada pelos _vendors_ dos _browsers_ atualmente em uso, e a pessoa é obrigada a instalar a raiz "na mão" e acreditar cegamente que essa certificadora não vai ter problemas de má administração e nem problemas com desvio de finalidade ou de funcionário/fornecedor. A questão da raiz ICP Brasil é um dos pontos fundamentais para responder parte da pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco Eu dei o exemplo do CACert porque fundamentalmente ele é muito semelhante ao do ICP-Brasil: ambos são usados por um grande número de sites, ambos não são considerados "confiáveis" pelos *browsers*, ambos você tem que baixar e instalar o certificado raiz na mão, e em ambos tal certificado é servido por um canal inseguro. A diferença entre eles e, digamos, um CA privado criado por uma empresa, é que pra empresa é fácil distribuir o certificado raiz pra seus funcionários (num pendrive, por exemplo), mas esses outros são destinados ao público em geral.

Comment: Relevante: ["Installing a CA only for specific domains"](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/78776/6939) (ver também meu comentário na resposta do Thomas Pornin) e ["Certification authority only for certain domains"](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/31376/6939) (um pouco mais antiga, mas se as informações ali estiverem corretas, más notícias...)

Comment: @mgibsonbr aqui está um bom exemplo de como se pode perguntar quase a mesma coisa de uma forma muito mais objetiva e acima de tudo muito mais interessante.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> É necessário que um site tenha certificado válido para que a comunicação com ele seja segura? Por que?

Sim, é. Toda e qualquer requisição feita em cima de SSL requer uma chave que está contida dentro do certificado. O conteúdo da requisição é criptografado no servidor e enviado para o cliente, que descriptografa a requisição usando a chave do certificado.

Quando há algum problema com o certificado (não confiável, expirado, etc.) a inviolabilidade da comunicação não é garantida:

- Se o certificado não é confiável, significa que não há como garantir que a chave deste certificado está realmente protegida, pois não há como garantir a integridade da autoridade certificadora, e que ela pode ser reproduzida em um certificado falso, o que faz com que um atacante possa obter o conteúdo de suas requisições e que possa descriptografá-las e ter acesso ao seu conteúdo;
- Se o certificado expirou, significa que, por algum processo, algum atacante pode conseguir quebrar a criptografia e obter a chave. Há alguns métodos pra isso. Particularmente, quebrar SSL é complicado e demorado, mas não impossível.

Autoridades certificadoras possuem seu próprio certificado, que é chamado de certificado raiz. Os principais certificados de autoridades certificadoras são distribuídos pelos navegadores de Internet.

> Seria essa uma prática aceitável? [utilizar certificados do cacert.org]

Se você tem um site que lida com informações sensíveis, tais como dados muito sigilosos, de importância financeira, governamental ou corporativa, não, porque os browsers não distribuem o certificado raiz do CACert.org, e que portanto torna o CACert uma autoridade certificadora não confiável.

Para sites em que a segurança seja necessária, mas não num nível mais crítico, não vejo problemas. O CACert [utiliza um método de uma rede de confiança entre toda a comunidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAcert.org#Web_of_trust), ou seja, se algum certificado é reportado como inválido por alguém da comunidade, o certificado passa a não ser mais aceito por ela.

> Posso simplesmente dizer pros meus usuários ingnorarem o alerta de segurança e pronto, tal como esses sites do governo fazem?

Não deveria. Analogamente falando, é como se você tivesse uma fila de pessoas para entrar num lugar restrito por idade e não conferisse se os documentos delas são verdadeiros ou não.

Apesar de interceptação de SSL não ser comum no Brasil, não deixa de ser um problema de segurança.

> Que impactos um certificado inválido tem na segurança de um site?

Ele não garante inviolabilidade da requisição porque não atende aos requisitos de segurança do padrão SSL. Ou seja, não é garantido que as informações que circulam entre você e o servidor não possam ser interceptadas e lidas.

Comment: "Para sites em que a segurança seja necessária, mas não num nível mais crítico, não vejo problemas." Mas o que isso quer dizer? Que se um site exibir um alerta de certificado inválido, mas eu vir que o certificado veio da CACert.org, posso confiar nesse site desde que ele não faça nada importante? Qual a diferença entre fazer isso ou simplesmente não usar certificado algum? (i.e. usar só http)

Comment: A propósito, eu concordo com o que você falou sobre certificados expirados, mas sobre os "não confiáveis" eu tenho uma impressão diferente: não é que a chave dentro do certificado pode não estar protegida, mas sim que essa chave possa ser a chave de *outra pessoa* que não o dono do site que eu quero acessar. Pois não interessa ao atacante copiar a chave pública de alguém se ele não tem a chave privada, e sim colocar a chave *dele* no lugar da chave verdadeira, de modo que a vítima se comunique com ele e não com o site original.

Comment: Esse último ataque mencionado por você @mgibsonbr é o man-in-the-middle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14907718/2236741

Comment: Sobre sua dúvida, o correto seria orientar o usuário a instalar o certificado raiz do CACert em sua máquina e o problema seria resolvido (o de não avisar da invalidade do certificado). O problema é justamente este: isto requer uma ação manual que não garante a inviolabilidade do processo. O man-in-the-middle, apontado corretamente pelo @cantoni, diz exatamente isso.

Comment: Sobre "se um site exibir um alerta de certificado inválido, mas eu vir que o certificado veio da CACert.org, posso confiar nesse site desde que ele não faça nada importante?", eu não diria importante, mas sensível, e que pode ser respondido com uma pergunta: "Quão grave é a interceptação desses dados por um atacante?".

Comment: "O problema é justamente este: isto requer uma ação manual que não garante a inviolabilidade do processo." Concordo, se eu simplesmente disser pros usuários "vá pro site da CACert e baixe o certificado X" eles não estarão protegidos - pois o site da CACert em si *não possui* um certificado válido (i.e. assinado por uma CA reconhecida), então não pode ser confiado numa ação tão sensível quanto "instalar um certificado raiz". E de todo modo, ao pedir a instalação de um cert. raiz novo eu estaria exigindo que meus usuários confiassem não só no meu mas em muitos outros sites desconhecidos também.

Comment: @cantoni Obrigado pelo link, aliás a resposta linkada sumariza muito bem minha maior crítica ao sistema de ICP como um todo ("mesmo se você pagar por um certificado de alta confiança, o seu site não estará de forma alguma trancado ao seu certificado, você precisaria confiar em *todos* os CAs no *browser* do cliente já que qualquer um deles poderia gerar um certificado falso para seu site que seria tão válido quanto [o verdadeiro].").

Answer (score 10):

Se um site é destinado ao público em geral, a única maneira de garantir a autenticidade da comunicação sem intervenção manual é através de um certificado válido. Usar um certificado inválido é só marginalmente melhor do que não usar nada - pois reduz as chances de qualquer pessoa na rede monitorar (*eavesdrop*) a comunicação sem ninguém perceber, em especial em redes abertas como wi-fi público.

Esclarecendo: mesmo com um certificado inválido a comunicação cliente/servidor é confidencial e íntegra (pois o canal de comunicações é criptografado apropriadamente). Só não se pode ter certeza que você está se comunicando com o servidor certo... Ver a pergunta ["Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28828/215) para mais detalhes.

A [resposta do Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101614/215) já toca nos principais pontos (inclusive no [problema de se instalar novos certificados raiz manualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101611/quais-os-impactos-na-seguran%C3%A7a-de-um-site-que-possui-certificado-inv%C3%A1lido#comment207407_101614) no *browser*). Vou apenas complementar com o último item não mencionado:

> é seguro continuar utilizando-os apesar do alerta de segurança apresentado?

No geral, não, pois como explicado "os browsers não distribuem o certificado raiz do CACert.org, e que portanto torna o CACert uma autoridade certificadora não confiável". O mesmo vale pro ICP-Brasil. Sem saber se o certificado raiz é confiável, não há como diferenciar entre o certificado autêntico e um forjado. E mesmo se o usuário conseguir obter de alguma outra forma o certificado verdadeiro, "o correto seria orientar o usuário a instalar o certificado raiz do CACert em sua máquina".

Pra piorar a situação, muitos sites do governo não usam nem o ICP-Brasil, mas sim um certificado auto-assinado. As razões disso são desconhecidas, mas o fato é que alguns desses sites precisam ser acessados para realizar operações sensíveis, e não dá pra fazer *opt-out* (um exemplo recente é o eSocial, embora este caia no caso anterior da ICP-Brasil).

O que fazer então? Atualmente, não muito, mas há algumas opções:

- Abrir o site em alguns dias diferentes, em alguns computadores diferentes, e verificar o *fingerprint* do mesmo (suas assinaturas). Quando estiver confiante que não há problemas com o certificado - i.e. o mesmo certificado foi exibido todas as vezes, e não houve relato de invasões nesse período - adicionar uma exceção para *aquele certificado específico*, de modo que futuras visitas não mostrarão mais o alerta de segurança. Se o certificado mudar, ficar atento e repetir o processo, pois pode ser apenas uma mudança periódica (ex.: o antigo está pra expirar) mas pode ser uma tentativa de interceptação;

  - Nota: isso pode ser feito tanto pros auto-assinados quanto pros ancorados na ICP-Brasil.
- Fazer o mesmo com o certificado raiz da ICP-Brasil, ou talvez tentar obtê-lo por um meio mais seguro, e então instalá-lo na lista de Autoridades Certificadoras. É uma forma mais "extrema" da anterior - pois ao fazê-lo se passa a confiar na ICP-Brasil tanto quanto nas outras CAs, o que lhes permite assinar certificados para domínios arbitrários;

  - Nota: o padrão X.509 [possui uma funcionalidade chamada *"Named Constraints"*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/78783/6939), o que *a princípio* permitiria que o usuário confiasse em um CA específico apenas para emitir certificados para alguns domínios específicos - como por exemplo a ICP-Brasil só pra sites `.gov.br` e nenhum outro. Entretanto devido ao [mau uso do sistema de certificação pelos servidores e *browsers*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31382/6939), essa medida pode ser ineficaz na prática...
- Usar um modelo diferente de certificação. O projeto [Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_%28SSL%29), por exemplo, usa um conjunto de "notários" para em conjunto determinar a autenticidade de um site. A ideia é que embora executar um único [MitM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7051/215) seja factível, fazer múltiplos simultaneamente e em diferentes partes da internet é muito mais difícil. Dessa forma, um usuário poderia ao ver um certificado conferir automaticamente com um ou mais notários se eles também estão vendo o mesmo certificado, e se todos (ou a maioria, é configurável) concordarem, então provavelmente estamos nos conectando com o site certo. Infelizmente, no momento em que escrevo essa resposta, esse projeto anda meio morto...

Mas o ideal mesmo, para quem está disponibilizando um site que precisa ou se beneficiaria da criptografia, é obter um certificado de uma das CAs globalmente reconhecidas. Pois apesar de todos os [problemas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101611/quais-os-impactos-na-seguran%C3%A7a-de-um-site-que-possui-certificado-inv%C3%A1lido#comment207465_101614) é a maneira mais segura que temos disponível para o público geral, sem depender de configurações manuais complicadas e arriscadas.

Comment: Qual seria o procedimento/custo para as empresas donas dos navegadores(Mozilla, Google, cia) incluam nas suas distribuições as cadeias de certificados ICP-Brasil?

Comment: @renedet Dado o grande poder que as Autoridades Certificadoras possuem, a inclusão ou exclusão de uma AC é algo bastante sério, não sei dizer exatamente qual o procedimento ou custo (mesmo porque deve variar de fornecedor pra fornecedor) mas suspeito que seja trabalhoso e custoso fazer direito. Lembrando que uma única AC mal gerida ou ainda mal intencionada pode comprometer a segurança da internet inteira.

Comment: @renedet Falando especificamente da ICP-Brasil, eu acho improvável que ela seja incorporada nos principais navegadores mesmo que atendesse a todos os requisitos de segurança, simplesmente porque se trata de uma entidade governamental, e não de uma empresa privada. Se essas empresas não confiam nem nos próprios governos para gerir chaves (imagina depois das denúncias do Snowden se alguém confiaria num certificado emitido pelo governo dos EUA...), como é que confiariam numa AC gerida por um governo estrangeiro?

Comment: @mgibsonbr tá feia a coisa então... sobre a startssl, parece que mozilla e cia estão descontinuando a inclusão das cadeias nos navegadores, o jeito é começar a usar Let's Encrypt

Answer (score 0):

Olha conforme respondida anterior respondida o certificado digital tem as seguintes funções:

- Integridade: Prova que os dados não foram alterados
- Autenticidade:  Prova a autoria da pessoa
- Segurança : Mensagem não pode ser lido se não tiver a chave
- Não repúdio: A pessoa que enviou não tem como contestar que não enviou

> Muitos sites do governo brasileiro costumam não ter certificados de segurança válidos

Isso acontece pois o certificado expirou e foi trocado.Exemplo:
O ICP teve seu certificado expirado e ele comunica as Ac(Autoridades Certificadoras) para não utilizarem mais aquele certificado
Pois eles trocaram os certificados.Porém como os navegadores não atualizam toda a hora os certificados mostra que o certificado é não confiável porque não a lista não foi atualizada com isso continua aquele certificado expirado