# Usar HTTPS é o suficiente para proteger uma área de login?

Tags: segurança

Considerando um sistema no qual possua os tratamentos corretos do lado do servidor, validações e protegido contra ataques de injeção SQL, XSS e força bruta, seria suficiente **apenas encaminhar a área de login para o protocolo HTTPS** ou deveria **alterar algo no código para que eu possa usar os recursos do HTTPS?**

Minha intenção é **proteger contra uma possível interceptação de senha**, pois só é gerada o hash dela no lado do servidor.

Comment: A maior parte dos defesas eficazes contra MITM só pode ser encontrada no roteador ou do lado do servidor.

Comment: Qual exatamente sua dúvida? Você diz que o sistema tem os tratamentos corretos, depois pergunta se deve encaminhar a área de login para o protocolo HTTPS ou alterar algo no código. Exemplifique o que deseja. Qual linguagem, qual ecossistema é esse login?

Comment: Minha intenção é proteger contra uma possível interceptação de senha, pois só é gerada o hash dela no lado do servidor.

Comment: Qual linguagem você está usando

Comment: Seria algo mais conceitual, quero saber se o HTTPS é o suficiente pra proteger de uma possível interceptação de senha, independente da linguagem, e sim do que é enviado por POST para o servidor. Se ao realizar esse envio, alguém conseguiria ter acesso à essa informação mesmo se estivesse usando HTTPS. A questão de se eu **deveria** alterar o código se refere se à utilização do protocolo HTTPS e não lógica no envio. Pra ser mais direto possível, pra usar os recursos do HTTPS é só estar HTTPS na barra de endereço? Entende? PS: Estou usando PHP.

Comment: Https é um dos conceitos mais utilizados na segurança web. Não é 100%, mas ajuda muito, você pode buscar mais segurança utilizando de outros recursos, mas https não pode faltar.

Comment: Veja essa excelente [resposta](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=POST+%C3%89+SEGURO+SENHA) de @jsbueno para uma pergunta tão interessante quanto à sua.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O HTTPS é o protocolo HTTP sobre o protocolo SSL/TLS. A função do SSL/TLS é criar um **canal de comunicações seguro** pelo qual toda comunicação cliente/servidor será feita. Isso significa que:

- Independentemente do servidor utilizado, linguagem, etc, se o canal for estabelecido com sucesso a comunicação será **confidencial** (ninguém no meio poderá lê-la), **íntegra** (ninguém no meio poderá alterá-la) e **autêntica** (na outra ponta estará o servidor certo, e não um servidor fake).

  - Ou seja, não é preciso alterar nada no código pra usar os recursos HTTPS, pois a proteção ocorre na camada de transporte e não na camada de aplicação.
- Somente os dados *em trânsito* estão protegidos - se houver por exemplo malware no cliente ou no servidor, ou ainda um ou outro for invadido por atacantes, eles poderiam potencialmente ler/alterar os dados, pois eles partem/chegam em formato plano.

Em particular pro HTTPS, temos que alguns dados são públicos por necessidade do próprio protocolo (ex.: a URL/IP, pois é preciso saber *pra onde* enviar cada pacote), mas todos os demais são privados (inclusive as *query strings*, os dados passados via POST, e todo o conteúdo do corpo da resposta).

Para uma visão geral do protocolo, sugiro a pergunta ["Como o HTTPS (SSL) funciona?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28828/215). No início da resposta eu falei que "se o canal for estabelecido com sucesso..." e de fato é muito importante estar atento às precondições para que isso ocorra, o que pode sim exigir certa configuração adicional no seu servidor. Em particular:

- Use sempre um [certificado de segurança válido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101611/215): adquirido de uma Autoridade Certificadora confiável pelos browsers, dentro da validade, e cuja chave privada foi gerada por você e mantida sempre em sigilo. Sem isso, a *autenticidade* da comunicação poderia ficar comprometida.
- Somente habilite no seu servidor suites de criptografia seguros. É muito comum a configuração *default* de vários servidores aceitarem algoritmos fracos caso o cliente não dê suporte aos mais fortes. E um protocolo fraco poderia potencialmente ser explorado e comprometer a *confidencialidade* e *integridade* da comunicação.

  Como configurar corretamente varia de servidor para servidor, mas o site [SSL Labs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101611/215) possui ferramentas úteis para ajudar a avaliar a qualidade da criptografia no seu servidor (e também no seu *browser*, mas o foco aqui é o servidor). Ele não só detecta potenciais problemas no seu certificado, como verifica quais protocolos estão habilitados no seu servidor e que não deveriam estar, e dá instruções de como desabilitá-los.

  (veja por exemplo [o resultado da análise pro meu site pessoal](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=marcelogibson.com) - que é só um blog comum, nada de muito sensível - eu ganhei um C rsrs)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação @mgibsonbr, usei o site que me passou pra testar um blog que eu tenho também, deu grade A, mas eu acho que é por causa do Cloudflare, se for testar o certificado diretamente ao meu site sem passar pelo CF também dá "C".

Comment: Provavelmente o Cloudfare é mais restrito nos protocolos que aceita (note que o teste não é só - nem principalmente - sobre o certificado, os protocolos aceitos é que são o elo mais fraco), e isso é uma boa coisa. Mas desabilitar protocolos inseguros é relativamente fácil, na primeira vez que usei essa ferramenta no meu site ganhei foi um F... :P